# ¿Como hacer vocales en mayúscula o minúscula?

Tags: java, string

```
                    Scanner palabra = new Scanner(System.in);
                  
                    System.out.println("Ingrese una palabra: ");
                    String vocal = palabra.nextLine();
                    
                    
                    

                     System.out.println("Las vocales de: "+vocal+" son:");
                         

               for (int i = 0; i < vocal.length(); i++){

        if (vocal.charAt(i) == 'a'){
             System.out.println(vocal.toUpperCase());
        }
        if (vocal.charAt(i) == 'e'){
             System.out.println(vocal.charAt(i));
        }
        if (vocal.charAt(i) == 'i'){
             System.out.println(vocal.toLowerCase());
        }
        if (vocal.charAt(i) == 'o'){
             System.out.println(vocal.charAt(i));
        }
        if (vocal.charAt(i) == 'u'){
             System.out.println(vocal.charAt(i));
```

Voy realizar un programa que solicite al usuario una palabra.
El programa tendrá un procedimiento que recibe como parámetro una variable de tipo STRING. El procedimiento imprime en pantalla únicamente las vocales de esta variable String. las vocales fuertes las imprime en mayúscula y las vocales débiles las imprime en minúscula.
La funcionalidad del Scanner debe estar en el main.
Mi problema es que a la hora de imprimir las vocales en mayúscula o minúscula imprime todo el texto,¿como hacer que solo me salga las vocales de este mismo texto?

```
Pantalla final.
Ingrese una palabra: incubaciones
Las vocales de la palabra son:
i
u
A
i
O
E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `vocal.toUpperCase()` retorna la cadena `vocal` con todos los caracteres en mayúsculas y si el retorno de `toUpperCase` se lo pasas a `println`, obviamente te va a escribir toda la cadena.

Lo que podrías hacer, una vez sabes si el carácter es la letra que tú quieres, que eso ya lo haces, es pasar a mayúsculas la cadena y del resultado imprimir solo el carácter que estás usando:

```
System.out.println( vocal.toUpperCase().charAt(i))
```

y para las mínúsculas lo mismo:

```
System.out.println( vocal.toLowerCase().charAt(i))
```

Por otro lado, veo un problema en tu código y es que al teclear la frase inicial, alguna vocal ya esté en mayúsculas y en tus `if` solo comparas con la letra en minúsculas. Así que tal vez tengas que hacer algo como:

```
if( vocal.charAt(i) == 'e' || vocal.charAt(i) == 'E')
```

Otra opción sería que conviertas toda la cadena a minúsculas antes de recorrerla comprobando cada letra y entonces podrías dejar los if como los tienes. Eso ya es cuestión de gustos.

Comment: Excelente gracias por la explicación.